# trigger is giving ORA-04091 error

Tags: oracle, triggers, ora-04091

I have a after insert trigger on `table tbl_campboss_report` , but it is giving me
 `tbl_campboss_report` is mutating, trigger/function may not see it

this is my trigger:

```
BEGIN
update tbl_campboss_report c set c.units=(select b.units from tbl_campboss_master b where b.details=:new.details); 

END;
```

Can anyone help me on this?
Thanks in advance

Comment: You can't update the same records which are invoking the trigger, is `details` a unique key ? are you trying to update more than one record?

Comment: details is not PK and i update only one record

Comment: If the record you are updating is the same one you've just inserted then use @Noel's [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16632225/1083652)

Comment: This would be a much more efficient operation if you included the population of that column in the SQL that inserts the rows. It would also be more apparent where that value comes from. Of course it might be even more efficient to not populate it at all and get the value when needed from the tbl_campboss_master table.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider changing the trigger to BEFORE INSERT. You don't need to write UPDATE statement in your trigger. Simply assign the value to the required column.

```
:new.units = <value that you get from the query>;
```

Comment: [Here is a sqlfiddle demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/567b6/2) (I've already made it so it's a shame not to use it...)